# how to show gif(as a image) as a pop up while loading data in MVC app

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing MVC application. 
Application fetches huge data while loading.
I want to show loading image - .gif file while fetching records.

I have below code...

```
//Loads records when combo box changed.

        $(".vendorCls").change(function () {

            $('#loading').show()

               $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Product")',
                data: { vendorId: VendorId },

                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#productIndex').html(data);
                    $('#loading').hide()
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML Code :

```
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row-fluid" id="categoryDiv" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:10px;">
    <div class="listheading span9">
        <div class="span2" style="font-size:22px;margin-right:5px;">
            Products
        </div>


    </div>
```

but It didnt come properly, I want to show the loading gif as a pop-up,
how to do it  ?

Right now, it appears as below

[image]

Comment: You can use [Block UI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page).

Answer (score 0):

Put the following masking div on the page or _Layout somewhere and then control the display via the JS functions that follow. Its that simple:

```
<div class="main_dash" id="MaskedDiv" style="display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; background-color: #4D4D4D; opacity: 0.6;">
        <div id="busyImg" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; display: none">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/busy.gif")" alt="Loader" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note that the ApplyMaskingDiv() function also takes care (using an iframe) in case you have simply specified a div with id 'MaskedDiv'.. go through it.

```
function ApplyMaskingDiv(zIndex, showLoader) {

    var MaskedDiv;

    //MaskedDiv = z('MaskedDiv');
    MaskedDiv = ge('MaskedDiv');


        if (MaskedDiv == null) {
            MaskedDiv = document.createElement('MaskedDiv');
            MaskedDiv.id = 'MaskedDiv';
            document.body.appendChild(MaskedDiv);

        }

        // include a temporary iframe to make the ddl invisible/un-accessible
        var iFrameHtml = "<iframe style='position: absolute; display: block; background-color: #4D4D4D; opacity: 0.6; " +
                            "z-index: -1; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; filter: mask();' >" + "</iframe>";

        // Masking the whole screen    
        if (IsIEBrowser()) {
            MaskedDiv.innerHTML += iFrameHtml;
        }
        MaskedDiv.style.display = '';
        MaskedDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        MaskedDiv.style.top = '0px';
        MaskedDiv.style.left = '0px';
        MaskedDiv.style.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'px';
        MaskedDiv.style.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';

        var PageHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
            PageHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        }
        MaskedDiv.style.height = PageHeight + 'px';

        if (zIndex) {
            MaskedDiv.style.zIndex = zIndex;
        }

            if (showLoader) {
                $('#busyImg').show();
            }

}

//function RemoveMaskingDiv(zIndex) {
function RemoveMaskingDiv(zIndex, maskDivId) {
    //var MaskedDiv = $('#MaskedDiv');
    //var loader = $('#busyImg');
    if (isEmpty(maskDivId))
        maskDivId = 'MaskedDiv';
    var MaskedDiv = $('#' + maskDivId);
    if (MaskedDiv) {
        // Remove the masking from the screen    
        MaskedDiv.hide();
        if (zIndex) {
            MaskedDiv.zIndex = zIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
              $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Product")',
                data: { vendorId: VendorId },

                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#loading').show();
                }, 
                complete: function() {
                     $('#productIndex').html(data);
                     $('#loading').hide();
                }
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some simple CSSs, like this:

```
#your-loading {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: - px; // a negative value that equals half the height of the element
}
```

This is the simplest thing to do.